# what css selector needs to be used in this case

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have taken a 70-480 Microsoft exam this morning(HTML5,CSS3 and Javascript), and I found one question to be confusing/wrong/incomplete. The question is this:

you have a checkbox input and a text input on the webpage.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" /> 
<input type="email" id="txtEmail" disabled/>
```

The requirement is that, when a user checks the checkbox:
  `the email input should be enabled` 
when the user unchecks the checkbox
`the email input should be disabled
 the email input should have gray background`

You have the following script and style defined:

```
<style>
     (selector) {
background-color:gray;
}
</style>

<script>
var chkbox = document.getElementById("chkBox");
if(chkbox.Checked)
{
   document.getElementById("txtEmail").(selector) = (selector);
}
else
{
   document.getElementById("txtEmail").(selector) = (selector);
}
</script>
```

You can pick from the options given below to replace the `(selector)` in the above code. you can use the same option any number of times.

```
1)enabled
2)disabled
3)true
4)false
5)set
```

I know that for enabling and disabling I need to use option 2,3 and 4 as shown below. And for the other (selector) which is in CSS, I had no clue what option made sense there. It did not make any sense to me, do you guys think the question is wrong or incomplete?

```
if(chkbox.Checked)
{
   document.getElementById("txtEmail").disabled = false;
}
else
{
   document.getElementById("txtEmail").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: None of those options (1-5) could replace the CSS selector. The CSS selector would look like `#txtEmail:disabled { }`

Comment: Doesn't make much sense anyway since disabled inputs get a gray background automatically.

Comment: replacing (selector) with any of the options did not make any sense, I know that there is a #xyz:disabled. probably the styles section should have said #txtEmail:(selector) to make it more clear, but with that the answer would have been much more easier to guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `:disabled` selector, but it should have specified a colon in front of it, in my opinion

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_enabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link to select disabled input

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

```
input[type="email"]:disabled {
     background: #d3d3d3;
}
```